# show number of elements based on value selected from list

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, textarea

I can't quite figure out how to word this correctly for Google or SO.

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="howMany" id="amount">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and 3 `textareas` that are all set to `display: none;`

When option value 1 is selected, I want the first textarea to show. When option value 2 is selected, I want textareas 1 and 2 to show, and 3 textareas when the option value 3 is selected.

I know how to make elements appear with jQuery. I just don't know how to start it. Would I use a for loop? `.each()` or `.change()`? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: And where are the textareas in relation to the select? Are there only three textareas on the entire page?

Comment: They're right underneath the `select` box. There are only three on the whole page, but they all have unique IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the textareas have an ID related to the values...

```
$('select#amount').on('change',function(){
   var sel_value = $(this).val();
   $('textarea.description').each(function(){
      if ($(this).is('#'+sel_value)) $(this).show();
      else $(this).hide;
   });
});
```

Comment: Guessing, you want to show just one textarea, related to the selected option :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('textarea').hide();
    $('textarea:lt('+$(this).val()+')').show();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9XbkC/)**

Comment: @BlackSheep - Yup, with jQuery there's almost always more than one way to do something.